# Azure DevOps Self-hosted Agent Capabilities Ubuntu

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables

I'm building a packer image for Azure Devops based on Ubuntu 20.04 for self-hosting. But I can't figure out how I should be adding capabilities. I've installed things like Java and Android SDK and set environment variables for their paths. I can see these when I run `printenv` but they aren't picked up by the agent. I've stopped & re-started the service, the only way I can get capabilities is by adding them to the .env in the folder where the devops agent is installed and stopping / restarted. How should this work ?

Comment: What do you mean 'but they aren't picked up by the agent', if you run `printenv` in DevOps pipeline based on your self machine, the return value will be different?

Comment: this is when I'm connected using SSH. So I've been installing new software and trying to get the agent to recognise this as a new capability. My understanding is that these are picked up by the agent when it is restarted. This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#configure-agent-capabilities

Comment: Where/how did you set those environment variables? Are they properly associated with the account that will be running the agent? I'd try creating a trivial pipeline which targets that agent that has a single script task to run `printenv` and validate that what the agent sees is what you see.

Comment: I've set these as the devops user account, I've set this both with and without out su privilege. The environment variables are there, it's just when I re-start the DevOps agent they're not picked up. I just can't work out how exactly this should work, I have this working by echoing each capability into the .env file that's use by the agent ```echo ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_ROOT/android-sdk >>/opt/az_devops/.env```

Comment: Have you added the executables of these tools to the search paths? The agent doesn't just check the environment variables, it also looks up the executables it needs. Those executables must all be added to the path variables.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/b93f8f1f4e53ddf5d9cd25090db6f71b092d177c/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent/Capabilities/NixCapabilitiesProvider.cs